# Upgrading and deploying ASP.NET RC1 project to RC2 in web app

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, kestrel-http-server

I have a web app in ASP.NET Core RC1 in production and deployed in Azure  with thousand of users using day a day.

I'm now upgrading my web project to RC2, following the tutorials I have found on Google (for example: [Scott Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETCore10RC2UpgradingFromPreviousVersions.aspx), [Official Doc](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html), [Tutorial1](http://ardalis.com/upgrading-from-aspnet-core-rc1-to-rc2-guide), [Tutorial2](https://wildermuth.com/2016/05/17/Converting-an-ASP-NET-Core-RC1-Project-to-RC2), [Tutorial3](https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/migrating-to-rc2/))

I need deploy the version RC2 when I have finished the upgrade without lose service to my users.

Do I need to create a new web app for the RC2 version or can I deploy in the same web app?

What is the way to implement that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Azure Deployment Slots**. Develop and test your web application on you local, push it into the *Staging slot*. If it works fine there just swap the Staging Slot with the *Production Slot*. If the test fails there, don't worry, your actual application will still be running in production. **Swap them carefully**.

If you are using a storage with your web app, create a test (if possible) database in Azure for Staging Slot. If database is not an issue, you can use the same database with Staging and Production. Make sure that it works fine on your local system first.

Comment: My slots have RC1, not RC2 :( it not works for me but thanks

Comment: You can create another slot for RC2. If your RC1 is in final production slot, still does not work?

Comment: Ok I will test, but I think it not going to work :) thanks

Comment: This is a faster approach, if you are not comfortable with it, use another remote repo for your project for RC2 up and running and immediately attach your continuous deployment with that remote repo. (This technique will make your website unavailable for a while).

Comment: Actually I'm publishing from VS. I think Im going to create another project and migrate and later publish and later again change the DNS os something similar

Comment: You can deploy to a different Azure Deployment slot from within VS. Create a slot on Staging slot on Azure, and you will begin to see that slot (With the same name of your application having _staging_ written with right from the publish menu in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes I know, I need to test if the new slot that I will create has support to RC2. Just that. ;)